# How to get SNMPv3 by python with auth no priv?

Tags: python-3.x, snmp, cisco-ios

How to get SNMPv3 by python with auth no priv?
i try to do it with pysnmp but it not work.
device :switch CISCO 2960

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import UsmUserData, usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,usmAesCfb256Protocol
from pysnmp.hlapi import SnmpEngine, UdpTransportTarget, ContextData,ObjectType, ObjectIdentity, getCmd

snmpName =username
snmpPass = password
ipHost = ipAddress

auth=UsmUserData(userName=snmpName,authKey=snmpPass,authProtocol=usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,privKey='',privProtocol=usmAesCfb256Protocol)


data = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),auth,UdpTransportTarget((ipHost, 161)),ContextData(),ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', 0)))

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(data)
print(errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds)
```

I get Errors Whene try to print this data with any way
Errors:

```
>>> errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 401, in loadModules
    self.loadModule(modName, **userCtx)
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 377, in loadModule
    raise error.MibNotFoundError(
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: MIB file "IF-MIB.py[co]" not found in search path (DirMibSource('/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs'), DirMibSource('/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/instances'), DirMibSource('pysnmp_mibs'), DirMibSource('/home/alchimie/.pysnmp/mibs'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/sync/cmdgen.py", line 108, in getCmd
    cmdgen.getCmd(snmpEngine, authData, transportTarget,
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/asyncore/cmdgen.py", line 130, in getCmd
    vbProcessor.makeVarBinds(snmpEngine, varBinds), __cbFun,
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/hlapi/varbinds.py", line 39, in makeVarBinds
    __varBinds.append(varBind.resolveWithMib(mibViewController, ignoreErrors=False))
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/rfc1902.py", line 853, in resolveWithMib
    self.__args[0].resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/rfc1902.py", line 480, in resolveWithMib
    mibNode, = mibViewController.mibBuilder.importSymbols(
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 441, in importSymbols
    self.loadModules(modName, **userCtx)
  File "/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 410, in loadModules
    raise error.MibNotFoundError('%s compilation error(s): %s' % (modName, errs))
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: IF-MIB compilation error(s): missingcaused by <class 'pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError'>: MIB file "IF-MIB.py[co]" not found in search path (DirMibSource('/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs'), DirMibSource('/home/alchimie/Documents/django/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/instances'), DirMibSource('pysnmp_mibs'), DirMibSource('/home/alchimie/.pysnmp/mibs'))
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex i added the errors output.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you do this `from pysnmp.hlapi import *` and not those individual modules?

Comment: Also it looks like from the error that you don't have the MIB module available?

Comment: i Do , But i get errors.

Comment: During my research I noted that the old MIBs repository disappeared in the pandemic.  Here is a [link](https://github.com/lextudio/mibs.pysnmp.com) to explaining how to install MIBs locally. Additionally the owner of the `pysnmp` package passed away in 2022.  Here is a [status updated](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/429) on the project.

Comment: This is the new package -- https://pypi.org/project/pysnmp-lextudio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message suggest that you don't have the MIB files installed.  The current version of `pysnmp` is by [lextudio](https://pypi.org/project/pysnmp-lextudio) and not this [one](https://pypi.org/project/pysnmp/). Please ensure that that you have the updated version installed.

Here is some pseudocode based on the newer version of `pysnmp` Please let me know if you still get the same error.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

host_ip_address = ''

authentication = UsmUserData(
    userName= 'your_user_name',
    authKey= 'your_password',
    authProtocol=usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
    privKey='your_private_key',
    privProtocol=usmAesCfb256Protocol
)


iterator = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                  authentication,
                  UdpTransportTarget((host_ip_address, 161)),
                  ContextData(),
                  ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)

if errorIndication:  # SNMP engine errors
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    if errorStatus:  # SNMP agent errors
        print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(), varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1] if errorIndex else '?'))
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:  # SNMP response contents
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

*edit: pypi link was malformed*

Comment: you had solve my problem ,thank you a lot friend, bless you.